# How to rearrange this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you please help me to solve the following equation for $s$?

$$[w-s]^{-0.5}=[(1+r)s]^{0.5}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math stack exhange. Please show how you attempted to solve the problem. Surely you should know about the exponential rules.

Answer (score 2):

First convert the exponents to square roots:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{w-s}}=\sqrt{(1+r)s}\;.$$

Now multiply both sides by $\sqrt{w-s}$ to get rid of the fraction, and then combine the square roots:

$$1=\sqrt{(1+r)s}\sqrt{w-s}=\sqrt{(1+r)s(w-s)}\;.$$

Square both sides:

$$(1+r)s(w-s)=1\;.\tag{1}$$

If you multiply out the lefthand side of $(1)$, you’ll have a quadratic equation in the variable $s$. Bring everything to one side of the equation and apply the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert $$[w-s]^{-0.5} = [(1+r)s]^{0.5}$$ to $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{w-s}} = \sqrt{(1+r)s}$$ Now multiply $\sqrt{w-s}$ to both sides. This gives us $$1 = (w-s)(s + rs) \ \ \text{note I factored in} \ s$$ Now use the old rainbow rule or whatever you teacher called it to factor and we get $$1 = ws + rsw - s^2 + rs^2$$ we can rewrite this as $$1 = s^2(r-1) + s(w+rw)$$ then subtract the $1$ from each side and we have the equation $$s^2(r-1) + s(w + rw) - 1 = 0$$ then recall the quadratic formula $$s = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$ where $a = r - 1$, $b = w + rw$ and $c = -1$. Then you will be able to solve for $s$.